# sap.viz Pie chart: how to remove dimensions from legend?

Tags: sapui5, pie-chart

I have created a pie chart using sap viz library. My requirement is to add multiple properties from the data model in the tooltip when you hover over the section. I was able to achieve this by adding those properties as dimensions. However, the legend values also change (like AAA/India/10 - check the screenshot below) as I add further properties.

Is there any way I can omit the addition of the properties into the legend ?

[Remove dimension from legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNhW3.png)

Eg. in the screenshot above, the chart is between Store and Revenue. I want Country and Consumption to appear in tooltip but in the legend only Store name should appear.

Link for jsBin code: [`Link for code`](http://jsbin.com/fevocidome/1/edit?html,js,output)